# Using Index in foreach loop as variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

In this code, I am trying to use the index of the forEach loop as a way to access an array index. It works when I use a number, but not the index. Any insights?

```
   let postive = this.graphData.results[0].values
   let finalPostive = []

   // format array
   postive.forEach(function (item, index) {
        self.makeArray(finalPostive, item, index)
   })

   // make array function
   makeArray: function (newArray, item, index) {

       // Putting in a number WORKS
       obj["name"] = this.graphData.results[0].id

       // Using the index returns 
       // "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"
       obj["name"] = this.graphData.results[index].id

    },
```

Comment: The index probably isn't what you think it is.  Use the debugger.

Comment: The index is console logging 0, 1, 2 as it should though?

Comment: `index` is being driven ultimately by the number of items in `results[0].values`, while you're then indexing into `results` - is this your intention?

Comment: they are the same length arrays, so the index console logs 0,1,2. so i am apparently wrongly assuming that would be the same as results[0].id, results[1].id, results[2].id

Comment: Nothing in your question proves or even implies that they are same length arrays.

Comment: A data structure where `results[0].values` has the same length as `results` makes no sense. I strongly encourage you to verify that they are indeed the same length and then reevaluate your choice of data structure.

Answer (score 2):

You are `forEach`ing over `this.graphData.results[0].values`, but you are selecting `this.graphData.results[index]`. This is not matching up to the same number of indices that are present in `results[0].values`.

Try this:

```
obj["name"] = this.graphData.results[0].values[index].id
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. My question was bad and it was Vue related. This worked for me

```
 postive.forEach(function (item, index) {
    self.makeArray(finalPostive, 'pos', item, index)
 })

 // make array function
 makeArray: function (newArray, flag, item, index) {

if (flag === 'pos') {
    obj["name"] = this.graphData.results[0].id
  } 
  else {
    obj["name"] = this.graphData.results[1].id
  }

},
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're doing in terms of accessing the index is correct.  Here's another example to confirm:

```
var vals = ['val1','val2','val3'];

vals.forEach((val, index) => {
    console.log(`Index: ${index} | Val: ${val}`);
});

// Output
// Index: 0 | Val: val1
// Index: 1 | Val: val2
// Index: 2 | Val: val3
```

Can you give more info on what errors you're seeing?

Comment: He is getting index correctly from the `forEeach`; however, he is not using this index properly as he is iterating over `results[0].values` and then using index in `results[index]`.

Comment: Yeah, dodgy wifi, I see your answer now, and that looks like it's the solution

Answer (score -1):

Javascript has index built in as [i]. Also, your parameter in your function should be i instead of index.

Instead of
obj["name"] = this.graphData.results[0].values[index].id

Try
obj["name"] = this.graphData.results[0].values[i].id